# How do I overlay the status bar with a view or a window?

Tags: ios, ios6, rotation, uiwindow

Previous Title: Rotating a custom UIWindow over status bar results in black bars being displayed during rotation with iOS 6

I have created a custom UIWindow that I place over the status bar with a transparent background color.

When rotating, blacks bars appear and I don't know why:

[image] [image]

This only happens on **iOS 6**, whereas my device with **iOS 5** does not display the black bars.

In the **AppDelegate**, I create a **UIWindow**:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) GRWStatusBarOverlayWindow *statusBarWindow;

CGRect statusBarFrame = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];
self.statusBarWindow = [[GRWStatusBarOverlayWindow alloc] initWithFrame:statusBarFrame];
self.statusBarWindow.hidden = NO;
```

I set the **rootViewController** of the status bar window to a dummy **UIViewController**.

```
@interface GRWStatusBarRootViewController : UIViewController

@interface      GRWStatusBarOverlayWindow : UIWindow
@implementation GRWStatusBarOverlayWindow

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        self.rootViewController = [[GRWStatusBarRootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

        self.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar + 1.0f;
        self.frame = frame;

        self.statusBarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        self.statusBarView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.25];
        [self addSubview:self.statusBarView];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I have tried both with and without a Nib, and some other approaches, without complete success.

The closest I have gotten is if I leave the **rootViewController** **nil**, and then I do get rotations without the black bars, however I do get a message:

```
Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
```

I always prefer to have clean builds and executions without any errors or warnings, so I would like to find a solution that removes that message and the black bars. However, if that message is harmless, I will accept it, although then I have to wonder what other problems might result down the road.

Does anyone have any insight into this problem? Any guidance or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: You've seen this on an actual device? I once had a project where much what you describe would always happen in the simulator but never on device.

Comment: Those screenshots are from an actual device and ...

Comment: I'm not quite sure why I seem to be making this more difficult than I need to. Not sure why I introduced a view into this when setting the color of the window seems to do exactly what I want without the black bars. I need to investigate further but I'm hoping I just temporarily lost my mind and did something stupid.

Comment: Oh, that's right, this message: Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch. Hmmm

Comment: self.statusBarWindow.rootViewController = self.window.rootViewController; still produces that message

Comment: So it's likely you're just paying the price for ignoring the documentation: "To change the content your app displays, you can change the window’s root view; **you don’t create a new window**" and "Every app has **one window** that displays the app’s user interface on an iOS-based device display." (emphasis added)

Comment: There are a lot of opinions on both sides of this argument, but in order to overlay the status bar I need a new window, since I believe the status bar is displayed over the main window. It can be done, and depending on how one chooses to interpret documentation, it's acceptable. I don't want to rehash those arguments here, I just want a solution.